# XAML error with Community Toolkit control

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

This is a native UWP app in its first days of development, it's named FIFA. There is a pre-release package (by Microsoft) that gives me a DataGrid control, you can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/datagrid#sample-code). After I install this package on my solution I build a very simple XAML page, which has the following code. It's a grid with 3 columns:

```
<Page
x:Class="FIFA.Views.Input"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:FIFA.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls">

<Grid>
    <controls:DataGrid>
        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="A"/>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="B"/>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="C"/>
        </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Somehow, when I run this app, it immediately crashes after briefly rendering the UI. The call stack shows the following:

> FIFA.exe!FIFA.App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__5_0(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 53    C#

The highlighted line in the screenshot bellow is that line 53 in `App.g.i.cs`:
[image]

And when building the solution I get the following warning:

> The assembly "C:\Users\user_here\.nuget\packages\microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.datagrid\3.1.0-preview1\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid.dll" does not have a NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute on it. To be used in an app package, portable libraries must define a NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute on their main assembly (ie, the one containing code, not a satellite assembly).

**Things that I have already done:**

1. Address the `NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute` problem by adding the following to AssemblyInfo.cs `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]`. It did not get the warning to go away.
2. Try making another blank app, throwing in some basic XAML to render a simple DataGrid. It worked without any issues.

Given point #2 and the fact that this app is still very premature I could just make a new app and copy and paste the few lines of code I have. That is a last resort, I really want to learn more about debugging and tackle this head-on. So, if you have an idea of how to go about this, please let me know!

Comment: You could submit this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues

Comment: I ended up making a separate app and the issue is gone now. I checked differences and realized the app with the issue was running on a .NET pre-release so I think that was the issue. I will submit this anyways.